# add_filter hook not working in plugin's php file

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a plugin and it works fine when I call my code from my plugin's main php file but I want to run only once My external file is called in the plugin. I mean I want to place my function inside includes folder and in a file living there. like plugin folder/includes/file.php ... here is my code

```
 add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items',',my_custom_function');
 function my_custom_function ($nav){
 return $nav."<li class='menu-header-search'><a href='#'>Icon</a></li>";
}
```

Kindly let me know how can I make it work, it works in side plugin's main php file but does not work from other php files inside plugin includes folder.

Comment: did you include that file which has the above code ?

Comment: that file is actually beaver builder's front-end.php file ... which does not includes but only once put data to front end once that file called .... hope you get it now ... ?

Comment: please add the plugin code

Comment: how can I paste that much code here ... are you serious about this ???

Comment: the problem is simple I want to run my add_filter hook from external files inside folder of plugins ...

Comment: paste your code here https://ideone.com/  and share the url in post edit we cannot help you without plugin code, because it depends on the plugin

Comment: ok thanks for your time and help ... you don't have any clue what I want ... thanks again man

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you include your file from the plugins main file, just make sure it is included correctly.

```
include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/file.php;
```

This would include a file in an includes folder in your custom plugin folder, and would include an file named: "file.php". If you want to know if its been loaded correctly, just add an die() statement in the included file:

```
die('my include file has been loaded correctly');
```

Just remove the die() statement after you have an confirmation that its working :) Lastly you need to copy your callback function code and paste it in your included file. If your hook still does not work, then it might be something wrong with your callback function.

The documentation for the filter hook you are using:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/

Comment: But its required in other file and not needed in main plugin file ... read question again